# Crucible + git, all commits should be reviewed

Tags: git, atlassian-crucible

We are using crucible as review tool, but recently we get a requirement that all commits should be reviewed.

In the way that we are using crucible now it's possible to commit code but not create review for it. So technically there could be some commits without review.

So my question is there any suggestion to solve it, and have the same guarantee like in git pull request(for all code to be reviewed) but still have crucible as review tool?

From the way I see it now we could forbid push in our "main" branch and make pull request for it. But we need the tool somehow to detect that all the "difference" line have been revived in crucible (but I don't know if it's possible) and if not - show lines without review and forbid commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crucible by design has read-only access to the repository so it's not really possible to forbid pushing any changes with this tool. However, there are couple of features which can by used to help in your workflow.

- [Crucible plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.plugins.reviewcreator/server/overview) which creates a review for every commit automatically:
- [Review Coverage plugin](https://confluence.atlassian.com/crucible/review-coverage-report-298977474.html) which allows you to find which commits were part of a review or not.

If it's not enough for you and your use case really enforces reviewing **all** changes then you should be interested rather in pull requests than in code reviews.